# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image_tag'

Tags: python, html, django-templates, stack-overflow, operationalerror

I'm trying to run my project but it is showing like there is a operational error which is none type has no attribute image_tag. Below here is my coding

```
    from . import models

    def get_logo(request):
        logo=models.AppSetting.objects.first()
        data={
            'logo':logo.image_tag
        }
        return data
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this error quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify which package you are importing "models" from?
It would be helpful if you describe what exactly you are trying to achieve here with this "get_logo" function.
Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Its a django package

Comment: from django.db import models

Comment: This is the package. Iam new to coding can you please help me to solve it?

Comment: I think the import is being done incorrectly. You can refer to the below accepted answer to get better understanding about relative imports.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

from . import models

```
def get_logo(request):
    logo=models.AppSetting.objects.first()
    data={
        'logo':logo.image_tag
    }
    return data
```

just remove models.AppSetting.objects.first() and then take the path of any image and put assign it to logo it is going to be something like this
def get_logo(request):
logo="path of image you chose"
data={
'logo':logo
}
return data